# How to get earth-inertial or earth-centered coordinates of objects from PyEphem?

Tags: python, pyephem

I would like to get coordinates of objects in various **XYZ** coordinates, not where they appear in the sky. I'm interested in:

1. ECE:  "[Earth Centered
   Inertial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial)"
   (not rotation with the earth)
2. ECEF: "[Earth Centered
   Earth-Fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF)" (not inertial, also
   called "Earth Centered Rotational"
3. and some kind of solar system or ecliptic coordinates (sun or
   barycenter centered).

I've installed PyEphem, run a few examples, and have started to understand what's [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34487170/3904031), but so far the examples I've found seem to focus on how things appear in the sky.

Either a link to a useful "how to" or a simple example would be helpful. Right now I don't see where to go with the standard options:

```
In [55]: mars.
mars.a_dec              mars.g_dec              mars.radius
mars.a_epoch            mars.g_ra               mars.rise_az
mars.a_ra               mars.hlat               mars.rise_time
mars.alt                mars.hlon               mars.set_az
mars.az                 mars.hlong              mars.set_time
mars.circumpolar        mars.mag                mars.size
mars.compute            mars.name               mars.sun_distance
mars.copy               mars.neverup            mars.transit_alt
mars.dec                mars.parallactic_angle  mars.transit_time
mars.earth_distance     mars.phase              mars.writedb
mars.elong              mars.ra

In [55]: mars.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The old C library that PyEphem is a wrapper around does not, alas, always use (*x*, *y*, *z*) coordinates internally, and when it does it does not expose them so that Python can see what they were — the (*x*, *y*, *z*) coordinates are discarded once the angles have been computed.

For a newer astronomy library by the same author (as it happens, me!) that has been completely rewritten so that (*x*, *y*, *z*) coordinates are indeed available every step of the way, try taking a look at Skyfield:

http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/

In particular, look at how attributes like `.position.km` and `.position.au` let you get any position and decompose it into (*x*, *y*, *z*) Cartesian coordinates:

http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/positions.html

Comment: Well this is clearly the correct answer!! Somehow I found the de405 package but totally missed Skyfield. This looks fantastic - and elegant too! Thanks for the quick response too.

Comment: I was thinking of cross-posting this question in Space.SE since there may be more people who have an appetite for (x, y, z).  Currently there are zero questions (and only 7 for PyEphem).

Comment: I've been enjoying SkyField tremendously! I've asked a new question [here](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/13523/12102)